# aio_read from file error on OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, file-io, aio

The following code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char name[] = "abc";
  int fdes;
  if ((fdes = open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600 )) < 0)
    printf("%d, create file", errno);

  int buffer[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  if (write(fdes, &buffer, sizeof(buffer)) == 0){
    printf("writerr\n");
  }

  struct aiocb aio;
  int n = 2;
  while (n--){
    aio.aio_reqprio = 0;
    aio.aio_fildes = fdes;
    aio.aio_offset = sizeof(int);
    aio.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE; 

    int buffer2;
    aio.aio_buf = &buffer2;
    aio.aio_nbytes = sizeof(buffer2);

    if (aio_read(&aio) != 0){
      printf("%d, readerr\n", errno);
    }else{
      const struct aiocb *aio_l[] = {&aio};
      if (aio_suspend(aio_l, 1, 0) != 0){
         printf("%d, suspenderr\n", errno);
      }else{
        printf("%d\n", *(int *)aio.aio_buf);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Works fine on Linux (Ubuntu 9.10, compiled with -lrt), printing

```
1
1
```

But fails on OS X (10.6.6 and 10.6.5, I've tested it on two machines):

```
1
35, readerr
```

Is this possible that this is due to some library error on OS X, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: just fyi, 35 is `EAGAIN`, the spec reads "Because of system resource limitations, the request was not queued.."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`aio_return(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/aio_return.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/aio_return) exactly once for each asynchronous I/O operation.  According to the note on that man page, failure to do so will leak resources, and it apparently also causes your problem.  After you call `aio_suspend` to wait for the I/O to complete, make sure to call `aio_return` to get the number of bytes read, e.g.:

```
const struct aiocb *aio_l[] = {&aio};
if (aio_suspend(aio_l, 1, 0) != 0)
{
  printf("aio_suspend: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
else
{
  printf("successfully read %d bytes\n", (int)aio_return(&aio));
  printf("%d\n", *(int *)aio.aio_buf);
}
```

Also bear in mind these important notes from the [`aio_read(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/aio_read.2.html) man page (emphasis mine):

> The Asynchronous I/O Control Block structure pointed to by `aiocbp` and the
>        buffer that the `aiocbp->aio_buf` member of that structure references must
>        remain valid until the operation has completed.  For this reason, **use of
>        auto (stack) variables for these objects is discouraged**.
>
> The asynchronous I/O control buffer `aiocbp` should be zeroed before the
>        `aio_read()` call to avoid passing bogus context information to the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, aio_return saves my day. I'm aware of stack shortcomings, but that wasn't an issue since I always waited for the read to finish right after it started (useless, I know, this for a dumb homework).

Answer (score 0):

Try zeroing the `struct aiocb aio`?

The manual reads:

```
RESTRICTIONS
[...]
     The asynchronous I/O control buffer aiocbp should be zeroed before the
     aio_read() call to avoid passing bogus context information to the kernel.
[...]
BUGS
     Invalid information in aiocbp->_aiocb_private may confuse the kernel.
```

Comment: changed to something like      aio = malloc(sizeof(struct aiocb));
    memset(aio, 0, sizeof(struct aiocb)); and it didn't help, that must be something else.